# AS3 - I'm stuck in hittestpoint

Tags: actionscript-3, platform, hittest

I'm making a platform game with moving camera, and the player has sensors to determine where he needs to be placed in order to be on top of the platforms, whenever its slopes or just simple floor. When the camera isn't moving, the sensors are following the player properly, but when the camera moves to catch with the player, the sensors are following with a delay, and it seems that the hittestpoint they are doing it taking the previous frame camera coordinates, even though the camera's function is before the sensors function. I think the hittestpoint cant deal with just x,y coordinates and it needs the actual object to appear on the stage and then taking its coordinates. am I right? 
it won't be easy to just place the camera's function after the sensor's function, because then the sensors will be in a delay all the time.
what should i do? I'm really stuck.

this is the sensor's function:

```
function setSensors(sensor, location):void {
var hx = Math.round(player.x + location * Math.cos(0.01745329 * player.rot));
var hy = Math.round(player.y + location * Math.sin(0.01745329 * player.rot));
player[sensor.name] = false;
var a = 0;
while (a <= 21) {
    sensor.x = Math.round(hx + a * Math.cos(0.01745329 * (player.rot + 90)));
    sensor.y = Math.round(hy + a * Math.sin(0.01745329 * (player.rot + 90)));
    if (blocks.hitTestPoint(sensor.x, sensor.y, true)) {
        player[sensor.name] = true;
        break;
    }
    a = a + 1;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hitTestPoint` works in stage coordinates, so you should probably convert `player's` position to global first. Something like:

```
var playerGlobalPos:Point = player.localToGlobal( new Point ); // player.x/y in stage coords
var hx = Math.round(playerGlobalPos.x + location * Math.cos(0.01745329 * player.rot));
var hy = Math.round(playerGlobalPos.y + location * Math.sin(0.01745329 * player.rot));
```

Comment: On another note, you should debug draw the `sensor` positions - it'll help with figuring out what's going wrong

Comment: I'm not actually sure why the camera position affects your sensors - surely they're for player collision? the position of the camera shouldn't matter. draw `sensor.x` and `sensor.y` every frame to see where they are - it'll help you spot where the bug is

Comment: the camera is the blocks that are moving, so the sensors are supposed to collide with the camera (:

Comment: "and i already tried that, didn't help" - you tried drawing the sensor positions? where they in the right place?